# Installing PHYSX under WINE

Tags: nvidia, wine, kubuntu, 14.10, playonlinux

I installed ME2, but it asks for physx. I used following command to install physx:

```
./winetricks physx
```

And that resulted in:

```
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. If you encounter problems, 
please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call physx
Executing load_physx
Executing wine msiexec /i PhysX-9.13.0604-SystemSoftware.msi
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
```

---

PS. It seems physx cannot be installed, I even tried on PlayOnLinux.
Everything else is OK, just in case someone asks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1414995) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181490) that is a bug (As I understood) in wine, and  this problem is caused by compiling wine with gcc4.9, which triggers this bug/problem:
 https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36139. So reinstalling Wine to latest (stable ) version will solve the problem.

Before to start we need First to remove the installed wine using the command.:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove wine –purge
```

Then remove the `.wine` directory:

```
cd /home/zinovsky
sudo rm -rf .wine
```

Now we will add the wine repository to install the latest stable release of wine:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine
```

Configuration:

After that latest version of wine is installed, we need to run `winecfg`. This will create the `.wine` directory in our home directory.

Open terminal by pressing press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
winecfg
```

After the `.wine` directory is created, we can start installing some necessery DLL and Libraries to make wine fully functional. To do that we will install first winetricks, a script that will help us install all the needed DLLs and libraries the easy way

Open terminal and past the following commands :

```
cd /home/zinovsky/.wine
wget http://www.kegel.com/wine/winetricks
```

Now make winetricks executable :

```
sudo chmod +x ./winetricks
```

Now we will install the needed dlls and libraries (Note that you can add or remove libraries depending on your system.)

```
./winetricks d3dx9 droid winxp sound=alsa volnum vcrun2008 dotnet20 ie6 corefonts
```

If you have an Nvidia graphic card you need to install [physx Technology](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_new.html).

```
./winetricks physx
```

Some configuration can be done also from `winecfg` like configuring a system to set winever to XP : winxp, or set sound driver to use alsa sound=alsa.

*Now you have wine installed and configured to install latest Windows applications!*

If you want to play the latest Windows games you will need to make some more configurations in the windows registry:

Open terminal and type :

```
wine regedit
```

For further steps [here](http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-wine-to-play-latest-windows-games-in-linux-ubuntu-linuxmint-fedora/)

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the PHYSX installer from a website, then right clicking the file and selecting (open with -> Winetricks) That should get the installation working.

P.S. If the game has problems after all the installation is done and the game is opened, that's fine. Wine doesnt always work with all applications, especially games, since some game interfaces were programmed to only work on windows, and will do otherwise upon being used in a different OS that hasn't been adapted to the Ubuntu specifications.

Too bad there are very few games that are Ubuntu/Linux compatible.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  What website? Did you test this yourself?  Please [edit] your answer to improve the quality, drop me a note @Fabby and I'll come back and up-vote! Also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)** (tip: avoid "try" "might" in your answers and use "do", "will",... and then the answer will be excellent!)